# Transfer learning with Keras. What should the final layer activation be?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I refer to Keras documentation here: https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/ which demonstrated a typical transfer learning workflow

First, instantiate a base model with pre-trained weights.

```
base_model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights='imagenet',  # Load weights pre-trained on ImageNet.
    input_shape=(150, 150, 3),
    include_top=False)  # Do not include the ImageNet classifier at the top.
```

Then, freeze the base model.

```
base_model.trainable = False
```

Create a new model on top.

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
# We make sure that the base_model is running in inference mode here,
# by passing `training=False`. This is important for fine-tuning, as you will
# learn in a few paragraphs.
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
# Convert features of shape `base_model.output_shape[1:]` to vectors
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# A Dense classifier with a single unit (binary classification)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Train the model on new data.

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=[keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])
model.fit(new_dataset, epochs=20, callbacks=..., validation_data=...)
```

My question is why this example did not apply a sigmoid or softmax activation in the dense layer?

```
# A Dense classifier with a single unit (binary classification)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
```

This dense layer here has linear activation by default, wouldn't this make the model output a regression value?

Comment: The loss has the argument `from_logits=True`.

Comment: @Frightera I see, thanks! This should mean that when I run model.predict , I will need to apply a logistic function to the output of the model, is that correct?

Comment: Yes something like this: `tf.nn.sigmoid(model_preds)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that sigmoid and softmax are just squashing functions i.e.. they squash a value between `[-inf, +inf]` to `[0, 1]`. So when we want to interpret the output of a linear layer to probabilities we use a sigmoid/softmax layer.

Now coming to the question of why a sigmoid/softmax layer is not used, it because of the loss function being used.

```
keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
```

If you check the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy), when

- from_logits=True, the expected `y_pred` is in [-inf, inf]
- from_logits=False, the expected `y_pred` is in [0,1]

So you will have to use a sigmoid/softmax if `from_logits=False` in your loss function.

Answer (score 0):

the model will output a numerical value which is then compared with the binary value, either 1 or 0. The difference will create a loss which will then be reduced via back propagation which will drive the model output to the desired value. I think however it is better practice to use a sigmoid activation for the layer.
On another level they always warn you to initially freeze the weights of the base model for initial training because of exploding gradients. I have run at least 500 models using transfer learning by leaving the base model as trainable. As a matter of fact in general I get better results training the entire model for N epochs than I do if I first train the model with the base model non trainable for M epochs, then fine tune the model for K epochs where K + M = N. In other words for the same number of epochs I get better results training the entire model vs the two step process with the same number of epochs. The difference though is in general fairly small in terms of validation and test accuracy. Further they say that if you change the base model from not trainable to trainable you have to recompile the model. I do not think that is true based on the code below

```
from keras.utils.layer_utils import count_params
model_name='EfficientNetB1'
base_model=tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB1(include_top=False, weights="imagenet",input_shape=img_shape, pooling='max') 
base_model.trainable=False
x=base_model.output
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)       
output=Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.compile(Adamax(lr=.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 
trcount = count_params(model.trainable_weights)
non_trcount = count_params(model.non_trainable_weights)
print ('trainable parameters: ',trcount, '  non-trainable parameters: ',non_trcount)
```

if you run this the printout is

```
trainable parameters:  330506   non-trainable parameters:  6575239
```

now in the code below I make the base model trainable

```
base_model.trainable=True
trcount = count_params(model.trainable_weights)
non_trcount = count_params(model.non_trainable_weights)
print ('trainable parameters: ',trcount, '  non-trainable parameters: ',non_trcount)
```

The printout that results is

```
trainable parameters:  6843690   non-trainable parameters:  62055
```

so from what I see you don't have to recompile the model

Comment: Thanks for your answer! > "I think however it is better practice to use a sigmoid activation for the layer". That's what I thought too, which was why I was confused by the lack of activation in the last dense layer. @Frightera pointed out that the sigmoid part was pushed into the loss layer by `from_logits=True` .

Comment: I also amended my answer because I disagree that when you change the base model from not trainable to trainable that you have to recompile the model. The code shows that the weights become trainable without recompiling

Comment: @GerryP do you have any research to backup your claim about getting better result on training the entire model for full range of N epochs instead of first pre-training for M and then fine-tuning till N epochs? If so, can you please link it here

Comment: I have tested it both ways on many models and setting training True for the base model has always worked better. My notebook at https://www.kaggle.com/code/gpiosenka/transfer-learning-comparisons-f1score-99-7 demonstrates the two approaches.